# Value for Dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a code to get a specific value from Yahoo API. The problem is it matched the IF statement but it returns None and also again its going to the else loop for some reason. I am very new to python.

I want to get the value of key astronomy as return.

```
import requests
def walk(d = None,val = None):

    if val == 'astronomy':
        return (val,d)

    else:

        for k,v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                p = d[k]
                walk(d=p,val=k)

r = requests.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys',stream = True)

n = r.json()
b = walk(d=n)
print(b)
```

Comment: There's really quite a lot wrong with your walk function. How does the for loop know if the recursive call found the astronomy dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recursing, so when it finds `astronomy` it returns only from that call back into the loop.  You need to test the return value from your function and use that.  For example:

```
import requests
def walk(d = None,val = None):

    print("val:", val)
    if val == 'astronomy':
        return (val,d)

    else:

        for k,v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                p = d[k]
                rtn = walk(d=p,val=k)       # Changed
                if not rtn is None:         # Added
                    return rtn              # Added

r = requests.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys',stream = True)

n = r.json()
b = walk(d=n)
print(b)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick help and learnt a new thing. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pick up the keys or to have a recursive call just to pull out the value - as long as your data is nested in dictionaries within dictionaries all you need is to recursively iterate through their values until you find a one containing your key:

```
import requests

def find_value(data, key):
    if key in data:
        return data[key]
    for v in data.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = find_value(v, key)
            if v is not None:
                return v

r = requests.get(
    'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast'
    '%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D'
    '%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys',
    stream=True)

n = r.json()
b = find_value(n, "astronomy")
print(b)  # {'sunset': '3:57 pm', 'sunrise': '11:58 am'}
```

Comment: Thanks .. Let me have a look